# replacing letter in email address before @ SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to update the email address field. My Scenario is I have column containing email address and I want the replace to work on the string before '@'. Before '@' if the character is 'a', I want it to be replaced with 'b'.

for davidsmith@yahoo.com the result would be dbvidsmith@yahoo.com

Thank you

Comment: Have u tried anything yet. Is it SQL server or Mysql ?

Comment: Is this MySQL or SQL Server? They are different. Once you let us know that, I bet we can find a similar question somewhere on SO that has been answered.

Comment: Tag the only one DBMS (`MySQL` or `SQL Server`) that you are really using.

Comment: This is T-SQL. I had tried   Select Replace(left('davidsmith@yahoo.com ',charIndex('@','davidsmith@yahoo.com ')), 'a','b'). but didn't get the desired result.

Answer (score 3):

```
DECLARE @email VARCHAR(1000) = 'davidsmith@yahoo.com'

SELECT 
  REPLACE(SUBSTRING(@email,0,e.t),'a','b')+
  SUBSTRING(@email,e.t,8000)
FROM (VALUES (CHARINDEX('@',@email))) e(t);
```

**Returns:**
dbvidsmith@yahoo.com

Answer (score 0):

You can use `charindex()` :

```
select replace(substring(email, 1, charindex('@', email)-1), 'a', 'b') + 
       substring(email, charindex('@', email), len(email))
from table t
where email like '%@%' -- or
      charindex('@', email) > 0;
```

Comment: This solution worked out for one emailaddress. Thank you. But if I try to replace it with the column name and work on the whole table its throwing a error 'Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function'. How do I make it work for a column?

Comment: @Dibya. . .  seems one of them emails doesn't have char `@`. So, you need `where` clause.